# Ansible, EC2 and Instance Profile

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to create via ansible with the following code:

```
– name: Create EC2 Instance(s)

ec2:
  region: “{{ vpc_region }}”
  instance_profile_name: “{{ instance_profile_name }}”
  group: “{{ ec2_security_group_name }}”
  keypair: “{{ ec2_key_name }}”
  …..
```

Still it always output the following:

> TASK [scanner : Create EC2 Instance(s)] ****************************************
>   fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {“changed”: false, “failed”: true, “msg”: “Instance creation failed => InvalidParameterValue: Value (my-role-for-ansible) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name”}

Although i think i defined the right policies to my user in AWS as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14844231360000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/my-role-for-ansible"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Anything wrong with the above?

Comment: Did your playbook just created the IAM role immediatly before trying to launch the instance? In this case you could fall in this: "After you create an IAM role, it may take several seconds for the permissions to propagate. If your first attempt to launch an instance with a role fails, wait a few seconds before trying again."

Comment: Yeah i waited for it but it didn't help, this still failed.

Comment: An IAM instance profile name is subtly different from an IAM role.  You'd use [`aws ec2 create-instance-profile`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html#getting-started-create-ec2-role-cli) to create the instance profile, then add your role (with the necessary IAM permissions) to that instance profile.  The `InvalidParameterValue` error there _usually_ indicates _a)_ the named instance profile doesn't exist, or _b)_ it exists, but cannot assume the IAM role to which the profile points.

Comment: Indeed thx, that help by replacing with the instance profile instead of the role it solved the problem

Comment: @Castaglia, weird thing is I've been using instance profiles for ages and now just got this error: 

Instance creation failed => InvalidParameterValue: Value (arn:aws:iam::*****:instance-profile/ansible-demo-role) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid.

Many people were also complaining about race conditions but in my case I've had the the profile for 3 days and this just stated happenign after I upgraded my boto versions to support a different ansible module, github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15341.

Comment: @Castaglia I wonder if the problem is either Ansible, boto or the AWS API. There's another thread where people say to simply name the profile, instead of using its arn, but I've been using arns for ages: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/2_5IhgE4Z6M/kk1vifRzIOkJ. Here are my versions where this error ocurred: ansible 2.5.9, boto==2.49.0, boto3==1.9.82, botocore==1.12.82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you must create an additional IAM role, an instance profile.

You can attach an IAM instance profile to an Amazon EC2 instance as you launch it or to a previously launched instance. For more information, see [Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).

I resolved this issue by following [the console instructions section of these AWS docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

The key part is step 9 of the aforementioned instructions (linked above):

> On the Create role page, choose AWS service, and from the Choose the
>   service that will use this role list, choose EC2.

Once you associate the role with the specific service type (in my case, EC2), then it all works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Packer was throwing this error, and it was because a matching role did not exist.

For once an AWS doc was actually helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  RootInstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref RootRole  

  RootRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
```

ec2:

```
IamInstanceProfile: !Ref RootInstanceProfile
```

If you were creating everything with cloudformation, you need a role, but you can't reference the role directly. You have to make an instance profile that references the role. Then in the ec2 properties you can reference the instance profile in the IamInstanceProfile property.